# Unable to center text using text-align:center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, center, text-alignment

I don't know if this is because I'm using bootstrap, but I'm having difficulty centering text in my header element.  I have

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="logo" href="#">My Logo Text</a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Currencies</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

and I added this CSS

```
#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

but the logo text is not getting centered, as you can see here -- https://jsfiddle.net/vuout1bj/ .  What else do I need to do to center it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are centering your text that is inside of your `a` element. But your `a` element has a display property of `inline`. Your text **is** actually centered, but it's inside of the `a` element, and the width of your `a` element is determined by the contents. So the visual effect of what you are trying to achieve is not really visible.

Either put your `a` element inside a `div` (`div`'s have a display property of `block` by default), and give the centering property to that `div`:

```
   <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div style='text-align:center;'>
        <a id="logo" href="#">My Logo Text</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Currencies</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Or, just make your `a` element have the `display:block` property:

```
#logo {
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The align-center for the `<a ...`  element i unuseful  .. Try place your logo anchor inside a div width 100% and text-align center eg:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <a id="logo" href="#">My Logo Text</a>
    </div>
     ...
```